# Fillenotfounderror while not writing or opening a file

Tags: python

Good day,

I'm having a problem i can't really explain. The error i get is *"filenofounderror"* to my understanding of python. you can get this error while using open() and when using relative path to a file that is not in the same directory of the programme.

I'm an absolute beginner in programming and here's my code snippet below:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def fun():
    venv = run(("python", "-m", "venv", "env"), stdout=PIPE, stderror=PIPE)

    if venv.returncode == 0:
          activate = run(("source", "env/bin/activate"), stdout=PIPE, stderror=PIPE)
          if activate.returncode == 0:
              print("Virtual Environment created and activated!")
          else:
              print(activate.stderror)
    else:
        print(venv.stderror)

fun()
```

The idea around this is to create a setup file for a project that i'm working on and create all the database in place and create a development virtual environment with python during the setup phase.

In doing so i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sihle/Documents/Development/python/NewPass/setup.py", line 105, in <module>
    venvf()
  File "/home/sihle/Documents/Development/python/NewPass/setup.py", line 23, in venvf
    run(("source", "loco/bin/activate"), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source'
```

I have tried to run with os.system(). Although is works, it does not meet my internded use as i cannot or won't now if the returncode is 0 or the command is success or failed.

Comment: `source` is not external binary but a built-in into some shells like bash.   You probably will need to pass  `shell=True`  for  that run() call to work.

Comment: Why do you want to activate the virtual environment? Are you going to make more subprocess call or is that just a nice to have for the user? If you are going to make more subprocess calls you could simply point directly to the executable for the created virtual environment. Also note that there is a [venv.create](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#venv.create) function that you could use instead of that first subprocess call.